# What does the flip function do?

Tags: purescript

I am a newbie to purescript.  This is the book [Leanpub-purescript](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-testing-code-using-the-interactive-mode) in which I'm learning.  I can't understand what flip funtion is. Is that similar to swapping concepts?

```
> :type flip
forall a b c. (a -> b -> c) -> b -> a -> c
```

which means `a value goes to b, then b to a, then c is itself??`. I'm struck with this. Please explain flip concept and if the book I'm referring is not good, suggest some other materials

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `flip` function reverses the order of arguments of a two-argument function. Consider a simple `subtract` function:

```
subtract :: Int -> Int -> Int
subtract a b = a - b

subtract 4 3
-- 4 - 3 = 1
```

If `flip` is called on the `subtract` function, it changes which number is being subtracted from:

```
(flip subtract) 4 3
-- 3 - 4 = -1
```

It also works with functions of differing argument types:

```
showIntAndString :: Int -> String -> String
showIntAndString int string = (show int) <> string

showIntAndString 4 "asdf"
-- "4asdf"

(flip showIntAndString) "asdf" 4
-- "4asdf"
```

If it makes more sense to you, try looking at flip as a function which accepts a two-argument function as an argument and returns another two-argument function as a result:

```
flip :: forall a b c.
    (a -> b -> c) -- takes a function
    -> (b -> a -> c) -- returns a function with flipped arguments
```

One of the use cases for `flip` is when you want to partially apply a function, but the argument you want to partially apply is on the second place. You can then `flip` the original function, and partially apply the resulting function.

Comment: Thanks man. Seems cleared.  But whats the meaning of `(show int)` in the line `showIntAndString int string = (show int) <> string`

Comment: You're welcome. `show` returns a string representation of its argument. Much like `toString()` in other languages. E.g. `show 123` equals `"123"`. More information about functions and types in PureScript can be found on [Pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org). [Here's documentation](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-prelude/3.1.0/docs/Data.Show#v:show) for `show`.

Comment: This should be added to the purescript book. Very good real life applications